# What does "book" mean in the output of 'lscpu -p'?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-architecture

The `lscpu -p` command outputs lots of information about the CPU architecture. One of the columns is the "book number". What does "book" mean in this context?

Comment: Looks possibly like something for IBM's hardware: http://www.spinics.net/lists/util-linux-ng/msg04805.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more specific: a modular card for IBM mainframes that contains CPU, memory, and IO connections:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_book

Comment: This is correct. As I understand it they are called 'processor books' as far as LSCPU is concerned, but most of us call them "Blades" or the entire server a "Blade Server". Essentially you can add blades (or books) to this server architecture to increase its processing power.

Comment: @JNevill "[Blade server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_server)" is used for individual modules sharing an enclosure without cache coherence (unlike an IBM mainframe, a.k.a. zSeries, (or POWER — yes, some POWER-based systems use books and they are not mainframes — a.k.a. pSeries [iSeries also uses POWER]) "book").